# Laravel Eloquent "with" return relations with limit

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have simple Laravel relations between Category and Article models. I need to return the list of all categories with related articles.

**Test data:** 3 categories and 15 articles (5 articles per category).
**Expected result:** collection of all categories with 2 latest related articles for each category

By default case I should use something like:

```
Category::with('articles')->get();
```

It's ok - I got 3 categories. Each category has "relations" with 5 related records.

Next, I tried:

```
Category::with(['articles' => function ($query) {
    $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    $query->limit(2);
}])->get();
```

But this is the wrong way. This construction in "raw" query looks like:

```
select * from `articles` where `articles`.`category_id` in (select id from categories) limit 2
```

So it's returned me a wrong result as expected...
I need all categories and latest 2 articles for each category (3 * 2 = 6 records) this query returned just 2 records

Comment: it's just my typo... edited

Comment: Then at a glance, that should work just fine. Can you post the actual results instead of the generated query? It should be a collection of `Category` models, each with 0 or more linked articles.

Comment: `Category::with('articles')` should be 2 queries, not 1.

Comment: Look at "raw" query, please.  
```select * from articles ... limit (2)``` returned me just 2 records instead 6

Comment: You do have a limit 2 at the end.

Comment: at the end? and I'll get 2 categories... I don't need to set a limit for ```Category``` model. I need to limit related records to this model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no native support for this in Laravel.

I created a package for it: https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit

Use the `HasEagerLimit` trait in both the parent and the related model.

```php
class Category extends Model {
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentEagerLimit\HasEagerLimit;
}

class Article extends Model {
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentEagerLimit\HasEagerLimit;
}
```

Then you can apply `->limit(2)` to your relationship.